# How can I write a method to reverse any slice?

Tags: go, slice

What's the idiomatic way to write a method that operates on a "generic" array?

I have a typed array:

```
a := make([]int, 0)
```

I want to write a simple method that could operate on an array of any type:

```
func reverse(a []interface{}) []interface{} {
    for i, j := 0, len(a)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
    }
    return a
}
```

Using this method `a = reverse(a)` gives me 2 errors:

```
cannot use a (type []int) as type []interface {} in argument to reverse
cannot use reverse(a) (type []interface {}) as type []int in assignment
```

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface. Or in short: You cannot. You have to resort to reflection.

Comment: The pragmatic solution is to write one reverse function per concrete slice type you use. In the unlikely event that there are many types [generate the code](https://blog.golang.org/generate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until generics arrive (which will most likely be called [contracts](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-contracts.md)), reflection and interfaces are the only tools to achieve such generalization.

You could define `reverse()` to take a value of `interface{}` and use the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package to index it and swap elements. This is usually slow, and harder to read / maintain.

Interfaces provide a nicer way but requires you to write methods to different types. Take a look at the [`sort`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) package, specifically the [`sort.Sort()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort) function:

```
func Sort(data Interface)
```

Where [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) is:

```
type Interface interface {
        // Len is the number of elements in the collection.
        Len() int
        // Less reports whether the element with
        // index i should sort before the element with index j.
        Less(i, j int) bool
        // Swap swaps the elements with indexes i and j.
        Swap(i, j int)
}
```

`sort.Sort()` is able to sort any slices that implement `sort.Interface`, any slices that have the methods the sorting algorithm needs to do its work. The good thing about this approach is that you can sort other data structures too not just slices (e.g. a linked list or an array), but usually slices are used.

Answer (score 4):

Not that you can use generic in production as of now (as of 2nd Oct 2020) but for people interested in the upcoming go generics feature, with the latest [design draft](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md) of go, you can write a generic function `reverse` as below

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func reverse[T any](s []T) []T {
    for i, j := 0, len(s)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    s = reverse(s)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
[5 4 3 2 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Patience! According to the [latest draft proposal to add type parameters](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md) to the language, you will be able to write such a generic `reverse` function in a future version of Go:

```golang
func reverse[T any](s []T) []T {
    for i, j := 0, len(s)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    s = reverse(s)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/2AGPv6oYhyU))

---

For performance reasons, you may want to reverse the slice in place:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func reverse[T any](s []T) {
    for i, j := 0, len(s)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
    }
}

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    reverse(s)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/zr2gBPcK5no))